# SearchView для поиска в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть меню с SearchView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
        android:title="Поиск"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Как с его помощью, реализовать поиск в RecyclerView, заменив в моем коде TextEdit.

Вот сам код MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks, BludaAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

```
private AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
RecyclerView rvList;
private ImageButton btnClear;

DBHelper db;

private int currentLoader;
final private static int LOADER_BLUDA_RU = 0;
final private static int LOADER_BLUDA_ZARUB = 1;

BludaAdapter bludaAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    db = new DBHelper(this);

    txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

    rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,
            layoutManager.getOrientation());
    rvList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    btnClear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    bludaAdapter = new BludaAdapter(this);
    rvList.setAdapter(bludaAdapter);
    bludaAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", "");

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_BLUDA_RU, bundle, this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_BLUDA_ZARUB, bundle, this);

    txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            refreshCursor(s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    });

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
    String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id, filter);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    bludaAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    bludaAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    Cursor cursor;
    DBHelper dbHeler;
    final int loaderID;
    String filter;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id, String filter) {
        super(context);
        this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
        loaderID = id;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
        switch (loaderID) {
            case LOADER_BLUDA_RU:
                cursor = dbHeler.getRusBluda(filter);
                break;
            case LOADER_BLUDA_ZARUB:
                cursor = dbHeler.getZarubBluda(filter);
                break;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}


private void refreshCursor(String str) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", str);
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, bundle, this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    txtSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b && txtSearch.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(charSequence.length() != 0){
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", "");
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, bundle, this);
}

public void onClearBtnClick(View view) {
    txtSearch.setText("");
    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

}

Класс Адаптер

```
public class BludaAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludaAdapter.BludaViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }


    /**
     * Index of the name column.
     */


    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param context The Context the Adapter is displayed in.
     */
    public BludaAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setupCursorAdapter(null, 0, R.layout.item, false);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ViewHolder to use for this adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public BludaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BludaViewHolder(mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent));
    }

    /**
     * Moves the Cursor of the CursorAdapter to the appropriate position and binds the view for
     * that item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Move cursor to this position
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

        // Set the ViewHolder
        setViewHolder(holder);

        // Bind this view
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(null, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder used to display a movie name.
     */
    public class BludaViewHolder extends RecyclerViewCursorViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final TextView txtBludo;
        public final TextView txtRecept;
        public final Button btnLike;
        int like;
        int id;

        public BludaViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtBludo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBludo);
            txtRecept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecept);
            btnLike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnLike.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            // переменные id, like переносим в поле класса-холдера, чтобы был доступ из всех методов
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Bluda._ID));
            like = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Bluda.COL_LIKE));
            String bludo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Bluda.COL_BLUDO));
            String recept = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Bluda.COL_RECEPT));
            txtBludo.setText(bludo);
            txtRecept.setText(recept);
            // конструкцию с if-else упрощаем
            btnLike.setText((like == 1)? "В избранном":"Нет в избранном");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //int position = getAdapterPosition();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnLike:
                    mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(id, like == 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(id);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Если бы адаптер был с коллекциями, то вопросов нет, а в случае с курсором как быть?

Comment: ну у вас и здесь нет фильтрации

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei конечно она там есть, если внимательно посмотреть. все происходит в активити, а не в адаптере.

Comment: @pavlofff угу спасибо непроскроллил, там кстати и ошибка, я написал как внизу должно заработать, если там в DbHelper query настроен

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei не думаю, что там ошибка. Это я писал этот код в ответе на другой вопрос, он оттестирован и взят практически полностью с туториала по фильтру на основе CursorLoader на developer.android com

Answer (score 2):

```
String filter;
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();      
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            AppUtils.hideKeyboardClearFocus(searchView);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            filter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            return true;
            }
        });

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
             return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id, filter);
        }
```

Comment: но ведь это не будет работать для адаптера RecyclerView на основе выборки в Cursor через CursorLoader

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна просто перенесите то, что у вас в методе `onTextChanged()` в метод `onQueryTextChange()` из ответа. То есть напишите там:`refreshCursor(inputText);`

Comment: дык, да не увидел. Да там просто запрос в лоудер дать, сейчас напишу

Comment: в общем то вы предлагаете передавать строку фильтрации через поле класса, а не через Bundle.  - это равнозначные решения, но поля класса традиционно рекомендуется избегать по канону :)

Comment: А через Bundle как сделать? Я бы хотела вариант с bundle

Comment: Что такое AppUtils? и я вставила этот код в метод onCreateOptionsMenu у меня ошибка с переменной filter, требует чтобы она была объявлена как final

Comment: Также в этой строке ошибка компиляции какая-то  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);  что-то типа этого   Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener', required: 'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна сделайте то, что написано во втором комментарии к этому ответу. В вашем вопросе для передачи фильтра используется Bundle, в ответе - поле класса

Comment: Сам кусок кода из ответа куда вставить в моем коде?

Comment: AppUtils утилитарный класс не обращайте внимание, если у вас есть ссылка на гитхаб с этим кодом скиньте мне, можете в ЛС я отвечу быстрей. Просто предполагать тяжело, там мб рейс а мб потом просто query не работать